# Composer inserting a strange folder in required libraries, causing the classes to not be autoloaded

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

EDIT 2: Changed the question to reflect the underlying issue.

---

EDIT 1: Seems like the weird-folder part is the culprit. I tried on a new project with other packages as well and all of them (including dependencies) are reproducing this behavior.

[image: Folder tree image]

---

Original Issue:

I have implemented the Twilio SDK through composer. The project is quite old and and does not use any kind of framework or standard so what little order we may have has been implemented manually. We have our own autoloader so we do not use the psr-4 composer.json property.

My relevant project structure is as follows:

```
- api.php
- composer.json
- composer.lock
- vendor
- app
  - models
  - libraries
  - controllers
  - tools
    - bootstrap.php
```

`api.php` file is the entrypoint for the application for this use case, which includes in its first line our bootstrap file:

```
<?php
require_once("app/tools/bootstrap.php");
```

The bootstrap file then includes 2 autoloaders, my custom one and composer's (assume the `BASE_DIR` variable is working correctly as well as my autoloader):

```
require_once(BASE_DIR . '/vendor/autoload.php');
require_once(BASE_DIR . '/app/tools/autoload.php');
```

For reference this is my `app/tools/autoload.php` content, it is tailored to the project structure:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
    $autoload_folders = ["controllers", "models", "libraries"];
    $filename = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    foreach ($autoload_folders as $folder) {
        $path = BASE_DIR . "/app/$folder/$filename";

        if (is_file($path)) {
            require_once($path);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

When referencing `$twilio = new \Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);` after the autoloaders have been required I get `Uncaught Error: Class 'Twilio\Rest\Client' not found`.

If I print something from the `vendor/autoload.php` file it is displayed in my application so it IS being included.

This was our installation process:

```
composer require twilio/sdk
composer update
Added require_once('/vendor/autoload.php') to our bootstrap file
```

I've tried (and still won't work):

- Running `composer dump-autoload` with and without optimization (which shouldn't be necessary since we installed it fresh),
- Moving the autoload to be the first line executed on api.php as require_once('vendor/autoload.php')
- Putting the Twilio code right after requiring the autoloader

What DID work but I refuse to do it this way is requiring the Twilio autoloader directly (`vendor/twilio/sdk/<weird-twilio-folder-name>/src/autoload.php`)

I've worked with Laravel for quite some time and have some of experience with composer, this also USED TO work before and now isn't... I'm pulling hairs here, is there something I'm missing?

composer.json file for reference:

```
{
    "require": {
        "twilio/sdk": "^7.16"
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: `<weird-twilio-folder-name>` is strange. I just tried a brand new project and that file lives at `vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/autoload.php`

Comment: @ChrisHaas I'm using PHP 7.2.
The actual folder name is `vendor/twilio/sdk/twilio-twilio-php-f97c450/src/Twilio`. I've also deleted the vendor folder, both composer files and reinstalled from scratch various times and it keeps being generated this way.

Comment: That's very weird to me. Do you have something in your composer.json file that would affect the install location?

Comment: Nothing weird, added the full file at the end of my post! If I move the contents to conform to the structure you posted, it works... really strange this folder is being generated.

Comment: Are you using composer 2.x? Can you try a totally unrelated folder, just a brand new one, and run `composer require twilio/sdk` to see if that works as expected? I'm totally grasping at straws, I've never seen this without additional composer scripts, and even in that case I don't know why it would do this. Are you on the CLI direct, or in your IDE?

Comment: I'm using composer 2.6.6, the project is running inside a docker container so I just bash in and input the composer commands. I'll setup another folder to try to reproduce.

Comment: This is reproduced on a new empty folder. I tried with other libraries and they presented this behavior as well. Maybe it could be related to Docker? I added an image at the end of the original post.

Comment: I'm unfortunately at a loss here, I don't use Docker and can't really test anything. I saw some people talking about weirdness when their build process runs composer, but if you are bashing in directly that wouldn't affect you. Hopefully someone here has a fix for you!

Comment: Either way I appreciate your help, you found the culprit! Just need to find out why its being weird.

Comment: My only other recommendation is to reword your question. Your basic problem is that when you run `composer require abc/xyz`, instead of `vendor/abc/xyz/src` you are getting `vendor/abc/xyz/abc-xyz-PHP-abcdefg/src`. The fact that this is Docker may or may not be significant, but since your screenshots show other libraries, I don't think it is a Twillio problem. If you do this, and you decide to keep your existing question, too, place your edit at the top, otherwise it gets lost

Comment: You can tell Composer to scan files for classes, even if those don't follow any of the PSR guidelines. That should allow you to drop your own autoloader entirely, which I'd call good refactoring. Then, you only include the generated autoloader. BTW: You can step through the autoloader using XDebug, too. Also, use a recent Composer version. That said, trying to reproduce this in isolation is exactly the right approach. Eliminate all differences between the two setups step by step to find the cause.

Comment: Just some general notes, not necessarily directly related to the issue: 1. Do not delete `composer.lock` as that tracks the exact set of packages currently installed. Without this file composer will try to re-compute dependencies during which it can and will select different versions which may break your downstream application code. 2. Do not run `composer update` willy-nilly as it is basically the same as point #1. 3. `composer require` will pull in the specified package, its dependencies, and any required changes to shared dependencies, you don't need to follow it up with another command.